# Sqlite + Safari History.db

Tags: database, sqlite, safari, browser-history

Recently Safari moved from History.plist to History.db to save history information. I tried opening the .db file with a SQLite DB Browser - but strangely nothing happened. Does anyone have a clue what file format this would be - or whether it's encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake by myself.
Solution is to close Safari first, and then open the file using a sqlite reader.

Yves

Comment: thanks! I wondered why `sqlite3` didn't display any tables. BTW, instead of closing Safari, you can make and open a copy: `cp ~/Library/Safari/History.db{,.bkp}`.

Comment: true indeed, I'm using that method as well nowadays :)!

Answer (score 4):

In Catalina or Big Sur, if you get an Authorization or Access Denied Error opening history.db you may need to give Terminal.app or your Database Browser program Full Disk Access in System Preferences->Security.